# How to copy/assign an array via for loop

Tags: solidity, arrays

Here is the following code:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.11;
contract TestArray {
    uint[] public newOriginal;

    function TestArray(){
    }

    function copy(){
        for(uint i = 1; i<5; i++){
            newOriginal[i]=2;
        }
    }
```

}

Why it doesn't work? I was basically tried to copy one array to another and discovered that I can't even assign it via loop.

Comment: What error did you get?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the docs,

> Index access: If x is of type bytesI, then x[k] for 0 <= k < I returns the k th byte (read-only).

Basically, your function `copy()` is experiencing an off-by-one error.

Now do this:

```
function copy(){
    for(uint i = 0; i<5; i++){
        newOriginal[i]=2;
    }
}
```

Comment: OMG. what a shame. NO more coding after 1am.

Comment: I don't get it why this explanation matters. newOriginal above is not a bytesI array such as bytes32, so the index access is not read-only. However I can see the starting index is 1 which is incorrect.